# Put pow(N,levels) elements per level

Tags: python

Given a list
`L = [6,3,87,90,90,90,43,21,1]`

I am creating a somewhat tree like structure where each level stores pow(2,level) elements in an array

Here is a code I tried

```
from collections import defaultdict

def slotify(L):
    level = defaultdict(dict)
    ptr = 0
    try:
        for ref in xrange(len(L)):
            #print ref
            for count in xrange(pow(2,ref)):
                level[ref].update({ptr:L[ptr]})
                ptr += 1
    except (IndexError) as e:
        return level


slotify(L)
Out[297]: defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {0: 6}, 1: {1: 3, 2: 87}, 2: {3: 90, 4: 90, 5: 90, 6: 43}, 3: {8: 1, 7: 21}})
```

The output is correct.

I would like to know a better logic implementation, somewhat better code for this logic. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want it to be dictionary at each levels? Why not just a list?

Comment: @thefourtheye just corrected the logic again; Sure it can be a list. why not a dict if i may ask?

Comment: Why a dictionary is a beter question? Your not deleting anything so in all cases operations is faster or just as fast on a list than a dictionary. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: You should give this a try on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would've done it:

```
def slotify(L):
    level = []
    counter = 1
    while counter*2 <= len(L):
        level.append(L[counter-1:counter*2-1])
        counter = counter * 2
    level.append(L[counter-1:])
    return level
```

This loops through the levels and inserts them into "level" except for the last level which it just adds just the remaining few since it might not necessary be a full level.

You can even go a step further and and cache the counter*2 value to save on the multiplication (Adapted from Suggestion by user2290820)

```
def slotify(L):
    level = []
    counter = 1
    counter_n2 = 2
    while counter_n2 <= len(L):
        level.append(L[counter-1:counter_n2-1])
        counter = counter_n2
        counter_n2 = counter_n2 * 2
    level.append(L[counter-1:])
    return level
```

You can even go further and change

```
counter_n2 = counter_n2 * 2
```

to

```
counter_n2 += counter_n2
```

because of the way python handles things.

and for even more performance you can replace the append with += [] (See comments, another one by user2290820)

and even faster if you cache the return value from len(L) as you only need to calculate it once then you don't have to worry about the global lookup again.

Heres the code as it's now:

```
def slotify(L):
  level=[]
  counter=1
  counter2=2
  val=len(L)
  while counter2<=val:
    level+=[L[counter-1:counter2-1]]
    counter=counter2
    counter2+=counter2
level+=[L[counter-1:]]
return level
```

You won't be getting much faster than that.

The program flow is the same just optimized from the first one.

But I have to credit rickhg12hs. My code is faster than his (barely currently, I'm sure he can push his past mine again ;) ) with my setup (2.7.5 with Linux), but his code is nicer python than mine. (Mine looks a bit like a c program now)

Comment: you can even further that and reduce functions => level += [L[counter-1:counter_n2-1]] and level += [L[counter-1:]]
shows 4 func calls in ipython

Answer (score 1):

If lists are okay as mentioned in the comments, here's what I would try first.  Much higher performance answer below.

```
In [1]:  from math import *

In [2]:  L = [6,3,87,90,90,90,43,21,1]

In [3]: a=L[:]   # make a copy that gets trashed

In [4]: [[a.pop(0) for k in range(min(len(a),2**k1))] for k1 in range(int(log(len(a),2))+1)]
Out[4]: [[6], [3, 87], [90, 90, 90, 43], [21, 1]]
```

For more performance (more than 3 times as fast):

```
In [2]: L = [6,3,87,90,90,90,43,21,1]

In [3]: def slotify(L):
    return [L[(1<<k)-1:(1<<(k+1))-1] for k in range(len(L).bit_length())]

In [4]: slotify(L)
Out[4]: [[6], [3, 87], [90, 90, 90, 43], [21, 1]]
```

Comment: Although it's fits in one line (which is always cool) It's terribly slow. It's even slower than the OP's solution.

Comment: In 10 runs profiled with cProfile (Python 2.7.5 on Linux) where L has 5*10**7 values. It juggles between my and your code for speed by a ms (Although it is on your side more often, but not within 5% sd ;) )